# javascript constructing new object using reduce method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hello Im stuck with constructing a new object based on the backend respond.

Here is the respond that i've receive

```
acl:[
     {
       "user_type":5,
       "user_id":"c7e5cb45ba764ad7ad29b5bdd4f12128",
       "user_name":"John",
       "view":true,
       "modify":false,
       "remove":false,
       "modify_acl":false
     },
     {
       "user_type":5,
       "user_id":"f673beac0245462f8c71066536049e72",
       "user_name":"Allan",
       "view":true,
       "modify":true,
       "remove":true,
       "modify_acl":false
     }]
```

The requirement was to filter the respond to remove all of the properties with false value and construct a new array that hold the access control value (acl).The expected new object will be like this:

```
[
   { 
   "userType":5,
   "label":"c7e5cb45ba764ad7ad29b5bdd4f12128",
   "value":"John",
   "acl":[
          {"value":"view", "label":"View"}
         ]
   },
   { 
   "userType":5,
   "label":"f673beac0245462f8c71066536049e72",
   "value":"Allan",
   "acl":[
          {"value":"view", "label":"View"},
          {"value":"modify", "label":"Modify"},
          {"value":"remove", "label":"Remove"}
         ]
   }
]
```

Currently i'm using reduce method to remove all the false value. But I'm stuck to construct the expected result.

Comment: Please post your reduce code.

Comment: Sorry for that, here is my code

`const aclEnt=this.props.recDetails.acl_entries
 let filteruser=[]

        for(const acl of aclEnt){

           filteruser.push(Object.keys(acl).reduce((o, key) => {

            acl[key] !== false && (o[key] = acl[key])

          return o

        }, {}))
   }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the type of the property and take boolean for assigning a new label/value pair and omit false values. Otherwise take the key value pair and assign it to the actual object.

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is actually the better method of choice, because it returns an array, which is wanted.

By using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), the accumulator would never change, because it would be an array.

```js
var acl = [{ user_type: 5, user_id: "c7e5cb45ba764ad7ad29b5bdd4f12128", user_name: "John", view: true, modify: false, remove: false, modify_acl: false }, { user_type: 5, user_id: "f673beac0245462f8c71066536049e72", user_name: "Allan", view: true, modify: true, remove: true, modify_acl: false }],
    result = acl.map(o => {
        var r = {},
            acl = [];

        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (typeof v === 'boolean') {
                v && acl.push({ value: k, label: v });
            } else {
                r[k] = v;
            }
        });
        return Object.assign(r, { acl });
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```